Vite + react (frontend) access to backend node issue net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
I have the following setup:
frontend vite + react app which is running in docker container on public network (on aws)
backend node API which is running in docker container on private EKS
when I into frontend container run the 'curl <backend_url>/colors' command it runs successfully and returns the answer, but when exactly the same API url is called from app it fails with net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error.
All dockers, ports, security groups and so on are configured well (fact: curl requests from frontend docker container pass successfully).
Anyone have any idea what it can be related to ? How can I investigate the problem ?
I tried to use another solutions (not just vite, but pure react), but it fails as well with the same error.
I tried to create a proxy app in frontend docker container, but then I got the net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error on the access to the proxy app.

Hello, you have not given us much info. Here are some steps you need to make sure are configured well.
Ensure CORS is configured, Docker networking is correct, and Vite is bound to 0.0.0.0. Verify AWS security groups and ACLs allow traffic, and check for WebSocket issues with Vite. Review backend logs and ensure no timeouts or resource constraints. Use the browser's dev tools for debugging, and try alternative HTTP clients in your React app.

Frontend apps run in the browser. Your API needs to be publicly accessible unless you can run a reverse proxy to it

@IdrisSelimi "Vite is bound to 0.0.0.0"... if OP is running the Vite dev server in production, they've got much bigger problems.

You're right; my suggestion about binding to 0.0.0.0 was more relevant to Docker networking issues. For a production setup, the dev server should definitely not be used. The key issues likely involve ensuring the API is publicly accessible or running a reverse proxy if it's not. Additionally, verifying that the API's security groups and CORS settings are properly configured to allow access from the frontend is crucial.

Thank you for your answers.
@IdrisSelimi Please pay attention that the curl request to backend API from frontend docker container passes successfully and returns data.
So the issue is not related to security groups, ACLs or any AWS/docker configurations (if I'm not missing something).

@Phil I understand that app run in the browser, but it works through ec2 instance in the public AWS network which do have access to the backend (again, curl request works) or I'm missing something ?

Thanks for the clarification, Max. Given that curl works from the frontend container, it confirms that the network setup is likely correct. This points to an issue specifically with how the frontend app (running in the browser) is trying to access the backend. Since the API isn't publicly accessible, a reverse proxy might be necessary. Also, ensure that the frontend app isn't being blocked by CORS or any browser security features when trying to access the API.

@IdrisSelimi there is no any CORS error, but now when you are explaining (sorry, I'm really new in frontend work) it looks like the problem is really related to the fact that the backend API is not publicly accessible and that's why I can't get it from the the browser, but curl do works.
Do you have any tutorial or can you please propose a good way to solve that issue ? I know vite has built in proxy - will it help in such case ?

The problem was that the backend is running on private EKS (so it's not accessible from the browser = frontend app (internet)), but it is accessible from the docker container where the frontend app is placed (if everything is configured well).
So the solution is to use a reverse proxy which will redirect API requests from frontend (internet) into the private EKS endpoint.
